# Can one jump in ex mode?

Tags: ex-mode

Say I entered `:e bla/bla/bla.txt` and I realize I want to put a `!` after the `e`. Can I get there without using the arrow keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Command Line Window

You can use `cmdline-window` to edit the command line the same way as you would any other window. Enter into this window by pressing `<c-f>` while on the command line or use `q:` in normal mode.

There is a similar [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode on the subject: [Refining search patterns with the command-line window](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/refining-search-patterns-with-the-command-line-window/)

#### Command line mappings

The command line also has many of its own mappings to help navigate/modify:

- `<c-b>`/`<home>` to go to the beginning ([Some people](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rsi) remap this to `<c-a>` to match emacs/bash/readline)
- `<s-left>` or shift + left arrow moves to the left one `WORD`
- `<c-u>` clears the command line completely
- `<c-r>{reg}` will put the value of register, `{reg}` into the line
- Many more. See `Q_ce` for a quick review.

For more help see:

```
:h cmdwin
:h cmdline-editing
```

Comment: I didn't know about `<c-f>`, but I found that using `<Esc>` followed by `q:` showed me the unfinished ex mode command in my command line window.

Answer (score 1):

From [`:h cmdline`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-B):

```
CTRL-B or <Home>                                c_CTRL-B c_<Home> c_Home
            cursor to beginning of command-line
CTRL-E or <End>                                 c_CTRL-E c_<End> c_End
            cursor to end of command-line
```

I didn't see any other commands that "jumped" around and didn't use arrow keys. You could do: <kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>, then type `e!` (a bit convoluted, I agree).